# How can I modify kernel command line in CoreOS

Tags: kernel, coreos

I am trying to set 'net.ifnames=0' on the kernel command line for CoreOS. In older loads (including the current stable 647.0.0), you could mount /dev/sda1 and edit the grub.cfg file under coreos/grub/grub.cfg.

With the beta and alpha channels, it seems that this does not work anymore. Under /dev/sda1, I now see coreos/grub/grub.cfg.tar. Untarring the grub.cfg file, editing it and re-tarring it does not seem to change the kernel command line.

The change that I made to this file is to change

```
set linux_append=""
```

to

```
set linux_append="net.ifnames=0 "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grub.cfg.tar file on the boot partition is actually built into the grub image, so modifying it does not make a difference.

You can add a grub.cfg file on the OEM partition (/dev/sda6) that will be read during boot. For this instance, the following should work:

```
mount /dev/sda6 /boot
echo set linux_append="net.ifnames=0 " > /boot/grub.cfg
reboot
```